# RT - Ethernet for CorteX M4

Tags: open-source, real-time

I am currently building a small system and need a real-time capable Ethernet interface (soft real-time is sufficient). After a longer research I have stayed with the procedure of ProfiNet, because the software should be free of charge. Does anyone have experience with it and knows where I can find the lib (programmed in C / C++)?
The only important thing here is that it is level 4 of Profinet, where the communication runs over UDP and not over TCP/IP.

On Github I only found the TCP/IP version.